# rsync --exclude not excluding

Tags: backup, rsync, ubuntu-12.04, exclude

I'm using rsync on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server with the following script to back up all of `/`, however, whenever I run the script (as root), the directory `/backup` is *included*, when it *should be excluded*:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.password --delete -aAXzv --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found,/home/*/.gvfs,/home/*/Downloads/*,/backup/*,/var/spool/squid3,/opt/atlassian,var/www/\~*} /* fsbak@servername::fsbak
```

Why is this happening, and how can I make rsync ignore `/backup`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` in the script has fixed this issue. The curly brace expansion used in the script is a `bash` feature and, as such, is not available in `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

From the `rsync(1)` manpage:

```
      --exclude=PATTERN       exclude **files** matching PATTERN
```

When you specify `/backup/*`, you are excluding all **files** inside the directory, but not the directory itself. To exclude the directory, use `/backup`

Example:

```
$ tree test
test
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   └── 4
└── b

$ rsync -av --exclude=4 $PWD/test/a/ $PWD/test/b/
sending incremental file list
./
1/
2/
3/

sent 87 bytes  received 27 bytes  228.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

$ tree test
test
├── a
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   └── 4
└── b
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    └── 3

9 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: All of the files inside `/backup` are still being included in the rsync. I have tried changing it from `/backup/*` to `/backup`, and it doesn't help.